# Symfony 1: Dynamic database connection configuration

Tags: symfony1

sorry to trouble you this much. I just want to know that is it possible to have a dynamic data in the database.yml file. This is to be able shift my connection whenever i want to to other database. If it is possible, can you please elaborate how its done, what is the involve processes and why it is needed.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just put both databases in the database.yml file and access the appropriate one as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is not possible to have something like variables inside the databases.yml files without using dirty tricks on the command line etc. But you can define multiple databases (as for testing) or you can load the databases.yml at runtime,

`$file = sfConfig::get('sf_config_dir').'/databases.yml';
$content = file_get_contents($file);`

and change it with a preg_replace for the dsn. This should work but I would really not use it.

Comment: how about in symfony 2? @M.R

Comment: I am still maintaining a Symfony1 application and I am not really familiar with the details of Symfony2. But as the yaml standard is normally used for serialization of config files I would think it would make not much sense to have dynamic parts in it.

Comment: It's possible to use php inside databases.yml. Change requires cleaning the cache however.

Comment: @Marek Could you give an example on that?